# Does Play 2.3 support akka 2.3?

Tags: playframework, akka, playframework-2.3

I know play 2.2.* does not work with akka 2.3 but what about play 2.3?

I am trying to upgrade to new version of a library that depends on akka 2.3 but it conflicts with the version of play I currently have.

Comment: Play 2.3.x is on Akka 2.3.3 currently. What library is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As can be seen in the [`project/Dependencies.scala`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/project/Dependencies.scala)  file, Play 2.3.x includes Akka 2.3.3:

```
"com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.3",
```